# Как удалить массив если все элементы null, и удалить все последние элементы массива которые null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const calendarData = [
  [null, null, 1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null, null],
]

надо получить такой массив 

const newCalendarData = [
  [null, null, 1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const calendarData = [
  [null, null, 1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null, null]
];

const f = calendarData
  .map((item) => item.filter(Boolean).length && item)
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map((item) =>
    item[item.length - 1] !== null ? item : item.filter(Boolean)
  );

console.log(f);

// const newCalendarData = [
//   [null, null, 1, 2, 3],
//   [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
//   [9, 10, 11],
// ]
```